# Getting extension from private repo with composer

Tags: yii2, composer-php

I have to create a private yii2 extension on BitBucket, and install it in my projects with composer.

The SSH is set up correctly as far as I can understand, it was not at first - and I got an error "repo not found or you do not have permission" (or something of the kind).

The composer finds the composer.json, I removed it to test and I got an error message that "valid composer.json not found".

Now when i run `composer update` in my Git Bash it just prints *"Nothing to install or update"* and nothing appears in my `vendor/` folder.

I have no errors to go on here, any ideas are mostly welcome!

---

I've set up the repo and added the following files:

*composer.json*

```
{
    "name": "ext. name",
    "type": "yii2-extension",

    "description": "My desc",

    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Jorgen",
            "email": "jorgen@domain.com",
            "homepage": "http://www.domain.com"
        }
    ],

    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "support": {
        "source": "bitbucket.org/companyname/yii2-extensionname"
    },

    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "2.0.*"
    },

    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "companyname\\extensionname\\": ""
        }
    }
}
```

*.gitignore*

```
vendor/**
```

*models/Test.php*

```
<?php

namespace companyname\extensionname\models;


class Test
{

}
```

---

And I've added the following to my Yii2 project *composer.json*:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url":  "ssh://git@bitbucket.org/companyname/yii2-extensionname",
    }
],
```

**Update**

So I figured out that if I add my repo in this format it's found and downloaded, but the autoloader-psr4.php file is not updated with my autoloading.

```
"repositories": [
{
    "type": "package",
    "package": {
        "name": "vendor/yii2-extension-name",
        "version": "master",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "git@bitbucket.org:vendor/yii2-extension-name",
            "reference": "origin/master"
        }
    }
}
```

When I have

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://bitbucket.org/vendor/yii2-extension-name"
    }
],
```

I get the following error:

> Problem 1
>       - The requested package vendor/yii2-extension-name could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
>
> Potential causes:
>    - A typo in the package name
>    - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
>      see https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion for more details.
>
> Read https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md for further common problems.

There is no typos, its found and downloaded when I use `"package"`. But then the autoloader is not updated.I've also tried all sorts of variations with git@, https and  ssh. It always works as a package, never as a git or vcs.

**Edit:** oh, and minimum-stability is set to `dev` while troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *must* use the correct name:

```
{
    "name": "vendor/yii2-extension-name",
    "type": "yii2-extension",
```

That is usually your Bitbucket username followed by the name of your repository.

That will work with your repositories Composer setting:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://bitbucket.org/vendor/yii2-extension-name"
    }
],
```

Comment: Oh, i have that - i just removed it for the sake of this post

Comment: Wow, you're absolutely right - i had a small typo in the `"name"`-setting. Thank you man, i did not notice - nor did i know that was important.

Comment: Composer is very finicky - glad that you got it sorted :)